# Splice Function in Javascript is adding 4 empty rows to my array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove all the rows whose length is less than some value. I'am using Splice function in javascript to do this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {

    if (table[i].length<=6) {
         table.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

but two  rows with length:0 are being added at the beginning and at the end of my array  [this is the actual array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElfVC.png)
[extra rows added after being spliced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89DxQ.png)
whis is this happening?
how can i get rid of it?

Comment: `table[i].splice(0,i)` or something like it...

Comment: Why not just `table.filter(function(a){return a.length > 6;});`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to splice from the end to start, because if an element is spliced, the following elements are move a place in front of the array.

```js
var table = [
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [],
        [0],
        [],
        [],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [0],
        [0],
        [],
        [],
        [1]
    ],
    i = table.length;

while (i--) {
    if (table[i].length <= 6) {
        table.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

console.log(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {

    if (table[i].length<=6) {
        table.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
}
```

After deleting a row you have to decrease the index to the array because the elements of the array have been shifted by the precious removal.

Comment: You can remove for loop third statement and increase if not matched then there is no need for `i--`.Or maybe you can even use reverse count in for loop.